Can i use an enum type field on the request body spring boot
Is it possible to use an enum type field on the request body in spring boot e.g
public enum Status{
A,
B,
C
}

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Order{
   private Status status;
}

If its possible how do you handle its validation using spring validation.

It is possible to receive enum values in the request body, but it raises an exception if the value is missing.
Therefore, it's a bit safer to receive them using a CustomValidator.
public enum Status {
    A,
    B,
    C;

    public static Status translateStringToStatus(String statusString) {
        switch (statusString.toUpperCase()) {
            case "A":
                return Status.A;
            case "B":
                return Status.B;
            case "C":
                return Status.C;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported status: " + statusString);
        }
    }
}

Alternatively, you can handle it using a custom annotation as shown in the following link.
